# How do you defeat Bowser Jr. at the end of World 3?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

In Super Mario Galaxy 2, you have to fight Bowser Jr. who is in a giant robot suit sort of thing. You have Yoshi, and there are Bullet Bills flying at you. I've figured out that I have to get Yoshi to eat the Bullet Bills and spit them out at the blue domes on the front of the robot suit (twice on each side to fully destroy each one), but when it comes to hitting the one on the robot suit's back, Bowser Jr. turns around too quickly for me to be able to shoot him if Yoshi eats one of the Bullet Bills that come out of the robot suit's back.

Is there something I am missing here? I keep dying, and would love to be able to make it to the next world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to use a launch star to quickly get behind Bowser Jr. with a bullet in Yoshi's mouth.**  After destroying the domes on the robot's chest, position Yoshi underneath the launch star.  Eat a Bullet Bill, use the launch star to get behind the robot, and then shoot.  You'll then have to get back to a launch star to repeat the process.  I believe there are three available.

[This YouTube video shows how it's done.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTUKhr1-enk)

Good luck!